# MSSQL to Snowflake Data Type Mapping

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone have a data type mapping from MSSQL (Azure MSSQL) to Snowflake?

This is the current mapping I have:

```py
# Key: MSSQL, value: Snowflake
DATA_TYPE_MAPPING = {
  "BIGINT": "BIGINT",
  "BINARY": "BLOB",
  "BIT": "BOOLEAN",
  "DATE": "DATE",
  "DATETIME": "DATETIME",
  "DATETIME2": "DATETIME",
  "DOUBLE": "DOUBLE",
  "DECIMAL": "DECIMAL",
  "FLOAT": "FLOAT",
  "ENUM": "STRING",
  "SET": "STRING",
  "IMAGE": "BINARY",
  "INT": "INT",
  "INTEGER": "INTEGER",
  "LONGTEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "MEDIUMINT": "INTEGER",
  "MEDIUMTEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "NUMERIC": "NUMBER",
  "REAL": "FLOAT4",
  "SMALLINT": "SMALLINT",
  "TEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "TIME": "TIME",
  "TIMESTAMP": "TIMESTAMP",
  "TINYTEXT": "STRING",
  "TINYINT": "TINYINT",
  "VARCHAR": "VARCHAR",
  "VARBINARY": "VARBINARY",
}
```

I could not find a complete mapping. If someone knows about one, please let us know.

Comment: That's wrong. There's no `BLOB`. The Unicode types are missing. `IMAGE` and `TEXT` are legacy types replaced by `varbinary(max)` and `varchar(max)` since 2005. `DATETIME` is a legacy type as well, with several quirks, but it's still common due to inertia. `DATETIME2` is the "new" one since 2005, with configurable precision and no quirks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What types does *your* database use?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for correctly pointing out that "BLOB" is not a MSSQL data type. I have also included DATETIME2 in the mappings. The point of this table is to support the creation of an ETL job which converts MSSQL tables to Snowflake. I am interested in all possible types in this case, including legacy types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type mapping is described in [Microsoft SQL Server to Snowflake Migration Reference Manual](https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/microsoft-sql-server-to-snowflake-migration-reference-manual)

Appendix A: MICROSOFT SQL SERVER
TO SNOWFLAKE FEATURE MAPPING

Subsection: Data Types

Comment: I have changed the mapping based on the Microsoft SQL Server to Snowflake Migration Reference Manual you mentioned.  See my answer in this thread. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the manual [Microsoft SQL Server to Snowflake Migration Reference Manual](https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/microsoft-sql-server-to-snowflake-migration-reference-manual) mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73718237/2735286) I have changed the initial mapping to:

```py
MSSQL_SNOWFLAKE_DATA_TYPE_MAPPING = {
  "BIGINT": "NUMBER",
  "BINARY": "BINARY",
  "BIT": "BOOLEAN",
  "CHAR": "VARCHAR(1)",
  "DATE": "DATE",
  "DATETIME": "DATETIME",
  "DATETIME2": "TIMESTAMP_NTZ",
  "DATETIMEOFFSET": "TIMESTAMP_LTZ",
  "DOUBLE": "DOUBLE",
  "DECIMAL": "NUMBER",
  "FLOAT": "FLOAT",
  "ENUM": "STRING",
  "SET": "STRING",
  "IMAGE": "BINARY",
  "INT": "NUMBER",
  "INTEGER": "INTEGER",
  "LONGTEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "MEDIUMINT": "INTEGER",
  "MEDIUMTEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "MONEY": "NUMBER",
  "NCHAR": "VARCHAR",
  "NVARCHAR": "VARCHAR",
  "NTEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "NUMERIC": "NUMBER",
  "REAL": "FLOAT",
  "SMALLDATETIME": "DATETIME",
  "SMALLINT": "NUMBER",
  "SMALLMONEY": "NUMBER",
  "TEXT": "VARCHAR",
  "TIME": "TIME",
  "TIMESTAMP": "TIMESTAMP_NTZ",
  "TINYTEXT": "STRING",
  "TINYINT": "NUMBER",
  "VARCHAR": "VARCHAR",
  "VARBINARY": "BINARY",
}
```